# How do you resize a form element in a block?

Tags: 7, blocks

I have two blocks, one with a search forum(using drupal finder module) and an email invite module, and for some reason both input forms go outside the blocks borders.

Both are giving me two different problems.  The finder module's search bar is going beyond the block borders but the entire email invite block is outside the borders.

How do you adjust the size of blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [#size](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#size) and [#cols](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#cols) (textarea) attributes of the different form elements as appropriate. You can do that with a hook_form_alter() implementation if they're not your forms.

Additionally, you can also use CSS, using the [#attributes](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#attributes) property.

Comment: Thanks Berdir.  I'm new to this so does this mean I need to create a custom module with this? or is there a place to edit this within the existing modules?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a new module. You should be able to find enough information on how to create hook_form_alter() implementations both on this site and on other sites. See for example http://www.lullabot.com/articles/modifying-forms-drupal-5-and-6

Comment: I'm not the best at creating modules but I have created 2 already so I'll give this a shot.  Thanks Berdir.